# How to override activerecord's default attribute column associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, legacy

I'm working on a legacy database that is complete non-sense.  I have a table called movie that contains columns with names like c00, c01, c02 and so on.  The table also uses non-standard primary_keys.  So I've created a class called movie like this:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "movie"
  set_primary_key "idMovie"

  belongs_to :media_file, :foreign_key => "idFile" 

  def title
    self.c00
  end

  def plot
    self.c01
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to do something like Movie.find_by_title("Die Hard") and have it return the right result. Also I'd like to  be able to say Movie.create(:title => "Die Hard").  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just need a combination of [Sarah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162079/how-to-override-activerecords-default-attribute-column-associations/1162102#1162102) and [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162079/how-to-override-activerecords-default-attribute-column-associations/1162201#1162201):

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  # gives you Movie.find_by_title
  # and lets you chain with other named scopes
  named_scope :find_by_title, lambda { |title| { :conditions => { :c00 => title } } }

  # gives you
  #   movie.title
  #   movie.title=(title)
  # and
  #   Movie.new(:title => title)
  alias_attribute :title, :c00

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `alias_attribute`. Check out [Brian Hogan's excellent presentation](http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/rails_legacy_db.pdf) from RailsConf this year.

Comment: Excellent!  This removes the need for the methods defining the accessors and mutators but it doesn't let me search by the alias.  So Movie.find_by_title("Die Hard") still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The find_by_* methods use reflection, so it just isn't going to happen with Rails out-of-the-box.  You can, of course, define your own methods:

```
def self.find_by_title(title)
    first(:conditions => { :c00 => title })
end
```

The next step would be to iterate over a hash of column_aliases => real_columns to use as fodder for calls to alias_attribute and define_method.